# Mount Koajs app on top of Express

Tags: node.js, express, koa

From koajs.com:

> **app.callback()**
>
> Return a callback function suitable for the http.createServer() method to handle a request. You may also use this callback function to mount your koa app in a Connect/Express app.

Now I have an Express app that already starts its own http server. How can I mount a koa app on top of this existing server, so that it shares the same port?

Would I include the koa app as an Express middlware? Do I still use `app.callback()` for that?

Comment: Maybe "expressapp.use(koaapp.callback())"?

Answer (score 2):

`expressapp.use(koaapp.callback())` is fine. but remember, `koaapp.callback()` does not have a `next`, so there's no passing errors to the express app or skipping the koaapp once you use it.

it's better to keep them completely separate since their APIs are incompatible

```
var koaapp = koa()
var expressapp = express()
http.createServer(req, res) {
  if (true) koaapp(req, res);
  else expressapp(req, res);
})
```

Comment: Your conditional `if (true)` will always be true—consider revising your answer for more clarity if you really think a condition is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Since you need a server instance in order to mount a middleware on a specific `/prefix`, it would be something like

```
var http = require('http');
var expressApp = require('express');
var koaApp = require('koa');

// ...

expressApp.use('/prefix', http.createServer(koaApp.callback()));
```

Comment: does it really work?
it gives the following error
`Router.use() requires middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn)`

Comment: it seems the only way is to `expressApp.use('prefix', koaApp.callback())`